# AS3: Do I need to nullify Object references in methods?

Tags: actionscript-3

Lets say I have this code in the middle of a class method:

```
var obj:Custom = new Custom();
```

Is there any reason, before the end of the method, to do the following?

```
obj = null;
```

Surprisingly, I haven't found a concrete answer here.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: the assignment of null is useless.

When the method/function returns the scope (aka: function context) and all variables in it cease to be [reachability roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29#Reachability_of_an_object) - *unless* there is a closure binding.

The only reason for this, aside from logic that depends upon the value of the variable, would be in *rare* cases if the method/function returns a long-lived closure that can maintain a "long lifetime" over the scope (and thus perhaps some variables/objects which the closure *doesn't* need that are no longer strongly reachable elsewhere).

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by a closure?

Comment: @JS In AS/JS a closure is effectively a "function created in the current scope which is returned from or passed to a different scope". An example of this is callbacks. See http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2006/12/04/closures-in-actionscript ,  http://grumblecode.blogspot.com/2010/03/closures-in-actionscript.html , etc.

Comment: Ahh, alright.  I'm familiar with JavaScript but not so much with ActionScript, so that example helped.  Thanks!